# JavaScript. forEach return an undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach

So, I have a simple part of code, where I need to process an array of objects and get know if there `availability.prop1` prop of some object inside an array equal to `true` and return `true` for it, or if it equal to `false`, then return `false`. It's very simple case, I know, but for some reasons I cannot figure out where is my fall...

And what is I'm expecting on the output, that `isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = true`, because the 2nd object inside an array `data` has a positive `prop1` value (`true`)

```
const data = [
 {prop1: false, {prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: true, {prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: false, {prop2: 'someValue'}
]

const isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = data.forEach(availability => {
  if (availability.prop1 === true) {
    return true
  }

  return false
})

// expected: isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = true (that's what I nedd)
// current: isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = undefined (wrong)
```

Comment: You can't return from a forEach loop.

Comment: please add what you like to check, every element or just one which with a short circuit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `.some` to check if any items in an array pass a test. `forEach` returns `undefined`:

```js
const data = [
 {prop1: false, prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: true, prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: false, prop2: 'someValue'}
]

const isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = data.some(({ prop1 }) => prop1 === true);
console.log(isSomeProp1EqualToTrue);
```

Comment: Thank you. I really forgot about such useful method as `.some`! :)
Cheers!

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if it worked for you @MaxTravis

Comment: @Sparky they will have to wait 15 minutes after posting their question before accepting an answer.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Good thing you tell me, I'm fairly new to StackOverflow as a contributor :) LearnSomethingNewEveryday

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce:

```js
const data = [
 {prop1: false, prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: true, prop2: 'someValue'},
 {prop1: false, prop2: 'someValue'}
];
var isSomeProp1EqualToTrue = data.reduce((total,currentValue)=>{
    return total || currentValue.prop1;
},0);
if(isSomeProp1EqualToTrue)
    console.log("Has some prop1 == true");
```